# Nginx location with routing

Tags: angular, nginx

I have an one page Angular project that contains multiple routers such as `/advance` `/home` `/profile` etc. and want to serve it with Nginx web server.

```
    index index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

but when I try to access pages with url like `server_ip/profile` it redirects me to default page or sometimes 404.

Comment: please share your nginx log file. it's probaply in /var/log/nginx/error.log